# ¿Es correcto hacer una pagina web sin Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy creando una página web, la primera, y estoy tratando de evitar JavaScript. Pero no sé hasta que punto eso es bueno para la propia página. Partes que se podrían haber hecho con java me las he ingeniado, con ayuda de tutoriales para hacerlo con CSS, cosa que fue muy productiva para aprender mas y buenas funciones de CSS. ¿Estoy escogiendo un buen camino?

Comment: Creo que esto es una pregunta que [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) contestará encantado. Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a su perfil y ver los ejemplos que tiene de webs sin JS. Por otro lado, las preguntas que se basan en opiniones, suelen ser mejor recibidas en [meta]

Comment: @rencinas los *meta* son para hacer preguntas sobre el sitio en sí. Si quieres saber qué se puede hacer o no en SOes, si has detectado un error en la página o no sabes para que sirve alguna funcionalidad, si quieres proponer algo o exponer un problema, entonces SOes Meta es donde preguntar.

Comment: te recomiendo leer [ask] y de paso checar el [tour] pues tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, lo cual son motivos para que termine cerrada, te comento esto por que no existe una única respuesta desde que no sabemos que va a contener exactamente tu página, si será solo una landing page o que harás?

Comment: @PabloLozano pensaba que las preguntas basadas en opiniones, o que puedan surgir debate se debían hacer en meta, pero por lo que me comentas, esas preguntas no tienen cabida en SO correcto?

Comment: @rencinas Correcto, pero puedes entrar al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) y ahí opinaremos de cualquier cosa :)

Comment: @PabloLozano Duda resuelta, muchas gracias lo tendré en cuenta!

Comment: Bueno, claro que es bueno, entre más conozcas sobre CSS menos dolores de cabeza tendrás en un futuro, yo he realizado y aún realizo páginas donde uso más CSS que JS, pero lo cierto es que depende del cliente o la necesidad, por supuesto una página sin JS es una página estática y simple (no en cuanto a diseño, sino en cuanto beneficios) para proyectos más complejos deberías de usar al menos JS y/o PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto que puedes hacer una página sin javascript, todo depende de lo que se requiera. 
También puedes hacer una página y utilizar bootstrap, por ejemplo para el entorno visual y estilos, pero integrar el javascript del bootstrap sin tener que conocerlo.

De todas formas, siempre por supuesto, es mejor conocer javascript, jquery, ajax... para crear páginas más profesionales donde debes ofrecer cierto tipo de efecto que de otra forma sería bastante complejo o lento de hacer.

Comment: Te invito a borrar tu respuesta hasta que el usuario cambie su pregunte , mira te invito a leer [Como Responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de lo que quieras conseguir, si lo que deseas es una página estática que muestre un contenido de una empresa, producto o similar, no necesariamente necesitas tener javascript.

Usar javascript es para darle algo más de funcionalidad a la página que con HTML no puedes conseguir.

Mi consejo, es que si te gusta el tema, ve aprendiendo poco a poco, porque en internet hay millones de ejemplos para ir aprendiendo poco a poco.

Un saludo

Comment: Chicos se les agradece el apoyo, pero preguntas basadas en opiniones no se deben responder